# I have integrate mpesa to nodejs code but RSA Encryption is not working me

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mpesa

Here is the reference link of code

https://developer.mpesa.vm.co.mz/documentation/#restfull-api

generate the encrypted authorization Bearer from the API Key and the Public Key

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

// Download: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String publicKey = "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";
        String apiKey = "aaaab09uz9f3asdcjyk7els777ihmwv8";

        System.out.println(getBearerToken(apiKey, publicKey));
    }

    private static String getBearerToken(String apiKey, String publicKey) {
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            byte[] encodedPublicKey = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKey);
            X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedPublicKey);
            PublicKey pk = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
            byte[] encryptedApiKey =  Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(apiKey.getBytes("UTF-8")));

            return new String(encryptedApiKey, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have already tried to convert this code to nodejs but it was not working for my end I don't know where i am making mistake in the code

Sample 1 -

```js
const ecKeyUtils = require('eckey-utils');
const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto');
const curveName = 'secp256k1';

const publicKeyTemp = 'MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAszE+xAKVB9HRarr6/uHYYAX/RdD6KGVIGlHv98QKDIH26ldYJQ7zOuo9qEscO0M1psSPe/67AWYLEXh13fbtcSKGP6WFjT9OY6uV5ykw9508x1sW8UQ4ZhTRNrlNsKizE/glkBfcF2lwDXJGQennwgickWz7VN+AP/1c4DnMDfcl8iVIDlsbudFoXQh5aLCYl+XOMt/vls5a479PLMkPcZPOgMTCYTCE6ReX3KD2aGQ62uiu2T4mK+7Z6yvKvhPRF2fTKI+zOFWly//IYlyB+sde42cIU/588msUmgr3G9FYyN2vKPVy/MhIZpiFyVc3vuAAJ/mzue5p/G329wzgcz0ztyluMNAGUL9A4ZiFcKOebT6y6IgIMBeEkTwyhsxRHMFXlQRgTAufaO5hiR/usBMkoazJ6XrGJB8UadjH2m2+kdJIieI4FbjzCiDWKmuM58rllNWdBZK0XVHNsxmBy7yhYw3aAIhFS0fNEuSmKTfFpJFMBzIQYbdTgI28rZPAxVEDdRaypUqBMCq4OstCxgGvR3Dy1eJDjlkuiWK9Y9RGKF8HOI5a4ruHyLheddZxsUihziPF9jKTknsTZtF99eKTIjhV7qfTzxXq+8GGoCEABIyu26LZuL8X12bFqtwLAcjfjoB7HlRHtPszv6PJ0482ofWmeH0BE8om7VrSGxsCAwEAAQ==';

const apiKey = "aaaab09uz9f3asdcjyk7els777ihmwv8";
var publicKeyTemp_base64 = Buffer.from(publicKeyTemp, 'base64');
var publicKeyTemp_utf8 = Buffer.from(publicKeyTemp_base64, "utf8");
const pems = ecKeyUtils.generateDer({ curveName, publicKey: publicKeyTemp_utf8 });
var publicKey = pems.publicKey

//generate key pair
generateKeyPair('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs1',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs1',
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    passphrase: "aaaab09uz9f3asdcjyk7els777ihmwv8"
  }

  // Handle errors and use the generated key pair
}, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
  publicKey
});

//Use the function to create and export the public key object
const publickKeyObject = crypto.createPublicKey(publicKey);
publickKeyObject.export({ format: 'pem', type: 'pkcs1' });
console.log(publickKeyObject)

//
const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt(
  {
    key: publicKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    oaepHash: "sha256",
  },
  // We convert the data string to a buffer using `Buffer.from`
  Buffer.from(apiKey)
);
console.log(encryptedData)
```

Sample 2 -

```js
const ecKeyUtils = require('eckey-utils');
const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto');
const curveName = 'secp256k1';

const publicKeyTemp = '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';

const apiKey = "aaaab09uz9f3asdcjyk7els777ihmwv8";
var publicKeyTemp_base64 = Buffer.from(publicKeyTemp, 'base64');
var publicKeyTemp_utf8 = Buffer.from(publicKeyTemp_base64, "utf8");
const pems = ecKeyUtils.generateDer({curveName, publicKey: publicKeyTemp_utf8});
var publicKey = pems.publicKey


const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt(
  {
    key: publicKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    oaepHash: "sha256",
  },
  // We convert the data string to a buffer using `Buffer.from`
  Buffer.from(apiKey)
);
console.log(encryptedData)
```

Comment: Can please format your code so that it is possible to see what code lies at E:\reactTest\nodetest\index.js:195:33

Comment: @JohnWilliams I have formatted my code I need to convert java code to nodejs code if there is any formatting issues in code you can see m-pesa link.
https://developer.mpesa.vm.co.mz/documentation/#restfull-api

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) then the following is all you need. You **may** need to tune the padding via the options argument.

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

const apiKey = "aaaab09uz9f3asdcjyk7els777ihmwv8";
const publicKey = "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";
 
var key = new NodeRSA();
var public="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"+publicKey+"\n"+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
key.importKey(public,"pkcs8-public-pem");
var encrypted = key.encrypt(apiKey, 'base64');

console.log('',  encrypted.toString("base64"));
```